# Yoga error building React Native from source

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I'm trying to build React Native from source to use some changes I made to its Camera Roll functions. I've followed the guide for how to do that, but I'm running into some downright arcane errors when trying to compile the whole thing.

Here's the whole pile:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: yogacore <= Utils.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: yogacore <= YGEnums.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: yogacore <= YGNodePrint.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: yogacore <= YGNode.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: yogacore <= Yoga.cpp

C:/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/../ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.cpp:228:1: fatal error: opening dependency file C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.o.d: No such file or directory
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.o] Error 1
make.exe: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

[armeabi-v7a] StaticLibrary  : libreactnative.a

C:/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/../ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodePrint.cpp:227:1: fatal error: opening dependency file C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodePrint.o.d: No such file or directory
 } // namespace facebook
 ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodePrint.o] Error 1
C:/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/../ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Utils.cpp:31:1: fatal error: opening dependency file C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Utils.o.d: No such file or directory
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Utils.o] Error 1
C:/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/../ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNode.cpp:668:1: fatal error: opening dependency file C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNode.o.d: No such file or directory
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNode.o] Error 1
C:/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/../ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp:3493:1: fatal error: opening dependency file C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.o.d: No such file or directory
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\tmp\buildReactNdkLib/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/yogacore/C_/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/__/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.o] Error 1

make.exe: Leaving directory `C:/Users/jon-g/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/kulaapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/jni'
:ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\jon-g\AppData\Local\Android\Ndk\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

None of this makes much sense to me. These file paths are entirely ridiculous.

Why is this happening? How do I get this to compile?

Comment: Make sure you have setup your NDK path correctly. Be sure to use only  android-ndk-r10e follow this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html. Make sure your Enviroment variables and Android local.property ndk.dir is referencing the same file. 
`ndk.dir=/Users/your_unix_name/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10e`
and `ANDROID_NDK=/Users/your_unix_name/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10e` referencing the same NDK file

Comment: Hey were you able to fix this error ???, I am also trying to build from source and facing same issue :(

Comment: @KarthikPala I'm also doing it for Android, after setting your ndk Path correctly you need to put this line `buildDir = "G:\\ReactNativ\\MyReactNativeAppProjectFolder\\"` in top level under allProjects -> repositories

Answer (score 1):

Append following in `Podfile`: (Ref: [facebook/yoga#711](https://github.com/facebook/yoga/issues/711#issuecomment-374605785))

```
def fix_cplusplus_header_compiler_error
    filepath = '../node_modules/react-native/React/Base/Surface/SurfaceHostingView/RCTSurfaceSizeMeasureMode.h'

    contents = []

    file = File.open(filepath, 'r')
    file.each_line do | line |
        contents << line
    end
    file.close

    if contents[32].include? "&"
        contents.insert(26, "#ifdef __cplusplus")
        contents[36] = "#endif"

        file = File.open(filepath, 'w') do |f|
            f.puts(contents)
        end
    end
end

def fix_unused_yoga_headers
    filepath = './Pods/Target Support Files/yoga/yoga-umbrella.h'

    contents = []

    file = File.open(filepath, 'r')
    file.each_line do | line |
        contents << line
    end
    file.close

    if contents[12].include? "Utils.h"
        contents.delete_at(15) # #import "YGNode.h"
        contents.delete_at(15) # #import "YGNodePrint.h"
        contents.delete_at(15) # #import "Yoga-internal.h"
        contents.delete_at(12) # #import "Utils.h"

        file = File.open(filepath, 'w') do |f|
            f.puts(contents)
        end
    end
end

def react_native_fix
    fix_cplusplus_header_compiler_error
    fix_unused_yoga_headers
end

post_install do |installer|
    react_native_fix
end
```

And modify `package.json` to fix fishhook error: (Ref: [facebook/react-native#16039](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16039#issuecomment-351100376))

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "sed -i '' 's/#import <fishhook\\/fishhook.h>/#import <React\\/fishhook.h>/' ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTReconnectingWebSocket.m"
}
```

Related PR:
[facebook/react-native#18492](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18492).

Comment: Hey @inDream This solution is for ios right? what about android?

Comment: Exactly the same error posted in the question. It was running fine in v0.52.0. When I tried to upgrade it is breaking. I found that the folder yogacore is missing in the build folder for latest versions where as it being downloaded in v0.52.0
I have also opened an issue here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18833

Comment: @KarthikPala see my answer, try it out and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

In Android, i fixed this error by doing the following:

First you need to make sure you setup your NDK enviroment correctly:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source.html

Make sure your environment variable  ANDROID_NDK path and 
`ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\jb\\android-ndk\\android-ndk-r10e`  (local.properties)
are configured correctly.

After that, in the Top level Gradle of your project add this line where you reference your React Native project location:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        buildDir = "G:\\ReactNativ\\MyReactNativeProjectApp\\etc.."
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Delete your build folders in the android folders, then do a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is embroiled in the windows [MAX_PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) limitation.

> In the Windows API ... the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters.

This happens because of recent changes that build yoga as a module, instead of simply including it as a library.  When building a module the NDK toolkit converts the relative path of the module source to an absolute path, and appends that to the gradle project `buildDir` so that the build can be absolutely, and uniquely identified.

When your project builds ReactAndroid, the `buildDir` is 
`C:\Users\jon-g\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\kulaapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\`, and the relative path to the `yogacore` source from the `projectRoot` is `../ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/`.

Add it all up with some contextual info about the build (`..\tmp\buildReactNdkLib\local\armeabi-v7a\..`) and you get the paths you're seeing above from having a relatively common project path (`c:\Users\[username]\OneDrive\[projectName]`). A path length of 437 characters for `YGNodePrint.o.d`.

How do we fix this?  Well, your first thought may be that you have the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, and you should just [enable LongPathSupport](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/)

> In the Registry Editor, use the left sidebar to navigate to the following key:
>
> ```
>  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
> ```
>
> [and set the `LongPathsEnabled` value to `1`]

This is by far the simplest solution, but it **absolutely will not work**.  Most of the tools in the `android-ndk-r10e` toolchain that *react-native* uses cannot properly interpret paths of more than 260 characters.  I don't have a thick enough beard to comprehend the hierarchy of the android cross compiler toolchain, but it would appear they realize that [most of the tools fail in this respect even in the most recent revisions](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/478), and fixing it does not appear to be trivial.

SO - *what I recommend*, is to simply follow the directions on the **Building React Native from Source** [page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source.html#additional-notes).  While they're concerned with not obliterating the cache, we're concerned with shortening the build path.

> ...you might want to change your build directory path by editing the `~/.gradle/init.gradle` file:
>
> ```
>  gradle.projectsLoaded {
>      rootProject.allprojects {
>          buildDir = "/path/to/build/directory/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
>      }
>  }
> ```

Set it to something short, and it may work.  If not, you have to move your `kulaapp` path closer to the root.

-OR-

If you're feeling particularly 133t today you could try to build the `react-native` framework separately using the `:ReactAndroid:installArchives` task so your build can just fetch your shiny new react artifact from `mavenlocal()`.  (This was the first thing I tried. It's not trivial and not recommended. No one on your team will like you.)